# Which video driver is faster, more stable? Which api makes it easier to write efficient code? Which one should I use on Raspberry 1 B+?

Tags: linux, opengles

**OpenSource** Full KMS VC4 + **Opengl** 2.0 + openbox/some lighter than openbox window manager/lack of thereof + **x.org**

**Broadcom** VC4 + **Opengles** 2.0 + **native**(no x.org)

> 

Can I use GLFW library with both?

Should I use GLFW library? And if I should how much easier would it be to develop an 3d application, how much of an improvement would I see over directly interacting with EGL/egl.h ,GLES2/GL2.h GL/gl.h libs/headers?

Besides easier porting to and from desktop platforms is there an advantage to using OpenGL in terms of creating a more readable ,maintainable and therefore faster and less buggy code. Or perhaps it is just that the open source gallium vc4 driver is just faster that it outweighs the the cost of running x.org.

Or should I use the closed source driver, and it's native(x.org less) rendering, years of stable code base from Broadcom(from what I heard the Broadcom VC4 driver is more stable, albeit that's an opinion from a year ago from reddit) and possibly(because I have no idea which is faster) better performance.

I added in linux tag since the question is also about the driver's performance.

Comment: Most stable is VC4. All of the new code with the overlays in config.txt is alpha code and doesn't always work.

Comment: @Dougie so as I understand it, closed source is the most stable(since the open source driver requires an overlay in config.txt). I will use that then.

Comment: It's closed source because it's part of the hardware. The DMS stuff runs on the Arm

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Note that vc4 also exposes GLES2, there's no reason you need to use desktop GL interfaces.